# WPF DataBinding Validation being ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I (believe) I'm wiring up DataBinding Validation in a textbook manner, but it just isn't working - at all.

In the debugger, the `Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)` method is never called.

What gives?  Also, for bonus points, any pointers on debugging WPF would be awesome.

I'm posting my XAML and the class in question

```
<UserControl x:Class="FooControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Name="GridFoo">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ValueConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxScalar" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="Scalar" NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:ScalarValidationRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlockUnit" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="3">
        <Hyperlink>
            <!-- Use a custom converter here b/c generics break wpf... -->
            <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Unit, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

ValidationRule

```
public class ScalarValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string number = value as string;
        double d;
        return new ValidationResult(Double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, out d),
            String.Format("\"{0}\" is not a number.", number));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are adding the ValidationRule to a one-way binding.  One-way bindings never push a value to the source, so there is nothing to validate and your ValidationRule is never called.  If you want to validate data entered by the user, set `Mode="TwoWay"` on your binding.  You can also omit the Mode attribute completely, since TextBox.Text binds two-way by default.

If you really do want a one-way binding and you want validation to occur when the value is pushed from the source (Scalar) to the target (TextBox.Text), then set [ValidatesOnTargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validatesontargetupdated.aspx) to True on the ValidationRule.  You can either do this in XAML or in the constructor of your ValidationRule class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the mode of binding. and set ValidatesOnTargetUpdated to false/true , based on your requirement,since both works.